# ¿Enviar una variable de PHP a HTML?

Tags: php, html, variables, variables-globales

tengo un problemilla. Necesito envidar una varible de un archivo en PHP en mi sitio1, a un archivo html en mi sitio2. este es el codigo que tengo hasta ahora

PHP sitio1=

`header ('Location: https://www.sitio2.xyz/ads/ad1/ad'.$variable.'.html');`

este es el HTML

`<META HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" CONTENT="0;URL=https://ejemplo.com/$variable">`

¿Alguna forma en la que pueda hacerlo?

Answer (score 3):

Puedes crear un bloque PHP dentro del HTML, la forma abreviada no suele ser compatible en diferentes versiones.

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" CONTENT="0;URL=https://ejemplo.com/<?php echo $variable; ?>">
```

Comment: Agregando que el archivo donde lo harás debe ser de extensión `.php`

Comment: Ese es el problema, necesito que el archivo sea extension .html

Comment: Si solo usas html en el sitio destino puedes leer una variable enviada por GET en el querystring utilizando javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Imagino que el html lo construirás a partir del fichero php que devuelve la respuesta. En ese caso, puedes incrustar código php en las líneas de html mediante `<?php echo $variable; ?>` o `<?= $variable ?>`, que es un abreviación del primero. Por ejemplo, en tu caso:

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" CONTENT="0;URL=https://ejemplo.com/<?= $variable ?>">
```